# Toogle ImageButton background faster on making flashlightlight app - "android studio"

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-imageview

I am very new to android studio, and currently I'm trying to build a **flashlight app** using the IDE. Everything is working really well, I am able to turn **ON** and **OFF** the flashlight of my device with the press of the ImageButton. Also I used the **.setImageResource** to change the background of the ImageButton to show the ON and OFF state. However, the problem that I am facing is that the change between the ON and OFF images are not fast (**not instant!!!**), it takes some time to actually change its background when the button is pressed. So if you guys could help me on how to switch between the two images faster for the ImageButton, I would really appreciate that.

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.android.flashlight;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageButton button;
private Camera camera;
private boolean isFlashOn;
private boolean hasFlash;
Parameters params;
MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // flash switch button
    button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button);


    // First check if device is supporting flashlight or not
    hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);


    if (!hasFlash) {
        // device doesn't support flash
        // Show alert message and close the application
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .create();
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setMessage("Sorry, your device doesn't support flash light!");
        alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // closing the application
                finish();
            }
         });
        alert.show();
        return;
    }

    // get the camera
    getCamera();

    // displaying button image
    toggleButtonImage();


    // Switch button click event to toggle flash on/off
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isFlashOn) {
                // turn off flash
                turnOffFlash();


            } else {
                // turn on flash
                turnOnFlash();
            }
        }
    });
}
// Get the camera
private void getCamera() {
    if (camera == null) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            params = camera.getParameters();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("Camera Error", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
// Turning On flash
private void turnOnFlash() {
    if (!isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;

        // changing button/switch image
        toggleButtonImage();
    }

}

// Turning Off flash
private void turnOffFlash() {
    if (isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.stopPreview();
        isFlashOn = false;

        //changing between images
        toggleButtonImage();

    }
}

/*
 * Toggle switch button images
 * changing image states to on / off
 * */
private void toggleButtonImage(){
    if(isFlashOn){
        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_on);
    }else{
        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_off);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // on pause turn off the flash
    turnOffFlash();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // on resume turn on the flash
    if(hasFlash)
        turnOnFlash();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // on starting the app get the camera params
    getCamera();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // on stop release the camera
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}


}
```

toogleButtonImage() is the method where I change the background of the ImageButton.

Comment: what are background images size in your drawable folder ?

Comment: Are you talking about value on the top right hand corner, this is what it says: 188 X 198

Comment: As simple "hack", you can use TWO buttons - one for turning on, the second - for turning off. And just change their visibility.